# Delay a MediaElement in Silverlight without holding up the UI thread

Tags: .net, silverlight, media, thread-sleep

I have a loop of audio files that need to be played in my MediaElement.

And need to wait 5 seconds between each one, I'm experiencing trouble with the UI thread being held up by the

`Thread.Sleep()` command. Is there another way to delay the audio file ?

```
        int _interval_time = 5000;

        ....

        //loop start

            Thread.Sleep(_interval_time); //holding up the UI

            media.Play();

        //loop end
```

I'm using Silverlight 5 (XAP) for a web control

Comment: Take a look at the timer class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob for that, here is what I created from the timer to solve.

```
        DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int counter = 0;
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            counter++;

            if (counter >= _interval_time)
            {
                _timer.Stop();


                //do stuff here


            }

        };
        _timer.Start();
```